# Segmentation fault - Cant find reason (debugged with GDB)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segfault i do not understand. I have the following code:

In main assigning filling the struct team and calling function:
TEAM team[NUMBER_OF_TEAMS];

```
  /* Initializing af team array*/
  int i = 0;
  int k = 0;

  for(i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_TEAMS; i++) {
    team[i].name = round[0].match[k].home_team;
    i++;
    team[i].name = round[0].match[k].away_team;
    k++;
  }  // The team array is filled rather funny because of the structure of the data I am using to fill it. There are 12 teams in a round of soccer matches and 6 home-teams and 6 away teams. Hence round[0] for both and this method.

int q = 0;
for(q = 0; q<NUMBER_OF_TEAMS; q++) {
  team[q].spectators_home_last_year = 0;
  team[q].matches_won = 0;
  team[q].matches_won_away = 0;
  team[q].matches_won_home = 0;
}




solve_task_three(round, team, teams_winning_away, &array_length); // Debugger claims
```

The function:

```
void solve_task_three(ROUND *round, TEAM *team, TEAM *teams_winning_away, int *array_length) { /* Wins more away than home*/
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int k = 0;


  for(i=0; i<ROUNDS_PR_SEASON; i++) { 
    for(j=0; j<MATCH_PR_ROUND; j++) {
      int home_team_wins = round[i].match[j].home_team_score > round[i].match[j].away_team_score;
      int out_team_wins = round[i].match[j].home_team_score < round[i].match[j].away_team_score;

      if(home_team_wins) {
        // GDB says this line is causing the segfault
        while(strcmp(round[i].match[j].home_team,team[k].name) != 0) { 
          k++;
        }
        team[k].matches_won_home++;
        team[k].matches_won++;
      }

      else if (out_team_wins) {
          while(strcmp(round[i].match[j].away_team, team[k].name) != 0) { // 
            k++;
          }
          team[k].matches_won_away++;
          team[k].matches_won++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I simply do not understand why the segfault is being caused and at this location. Any ideas?

EDIT: **Inserted  print statements in while loops, Output:**

```
i=0 j=0 round[i].match[j].home_team: FCN team[k].name:SDR
i=0 j=1 round[i].match[j].home_team: FCM team[k].name:FCM
i=0 j=2 round[i].match[j].home_team: OB team[k].name:VFF
i=0 j=2 round[i].match[j].home_team: OB team[k].name:OB
i=0 j=3 round[i].match[j].home_team: AGF team[k].name:HOB
i=0 j=3 round[i].match[j].home_team: AGF team[k].name:AGF
i=0 j=5 round[i].match[j].home_team: FCK team[k].name:BIF
i=0 j=5 round[i].match[j].home_team: FCK team[k].name:AAB
i=0 j=5 round[i].match[j].home_team: FCK team[k].name:EFB
i=0 j=5 round[i].match[j].home_team: FCK team[k].name:FCK
i=1 j=0 round[i].match[j].home_team: HOB team[k].name:RFC
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Beginning and end of iteration with i and j values.

```
i=0 j=0 round[i].match[j].home_team: FCN team[k].name:FCN
i=0 j=0 round[i].match[j].home_team: FCN team[k].name:SDR
i=0 j=1 round[i].match[j].home_team: FCM team[k].name:SDR
i=0 j=1 round[i].match[j].home_team: FCM team[k].name:FCM
i=0 j=2 round[i].match[j].home_team: OB team[k].name:FCM
i=0 j=2 round[i].match[j].home_team: OB team[k].name:VFF
i=0 j=2 round[i].match[j].home_team: OB team[k].name:VFF
i=0 j=2 round[i].match[j].home_team: OB team[k].name:OB
i=0 j=3 round[i].match[j].home_team: AGF team[k].name:OB
i=0 j=3 round[i].match[j].home_team: AGF team[k].name:HOB
i=0 j=3 round[i].match[j].home_team: AGF team[k].name:HOB
i=0 j=3 round[i].match[j].home_team: AGF team[k].name:AGF
i=0 j=5 round[i].match[j].home_team: FCK team[k].name:AGF
i=0 j=5 round[i].match[j].home_team: FCK team[k].name:BIF
i=0 j=5 round[i].match[j].home_team: FCK team[k].name:BIF
i=0 j=5 round[i].match[j].home_team: FCK team[k].name:AAB
i=0 j=5 round[i].match[j].home_team: FCK team[k].name:AAB
i=0 j=5 round[i].match[j].home_team: FCK team[k].name:EFB
i=0 j=5 round[i].match[j].home_team: FCK team[k].name:EFB
i=0 j=5 round[i].match[j].home_team: FCK team[k].name:FCK
i=1 j=0 round[i].match[j].home_team: HOB team[k].name:FCK
i=1 j=0 round[i].match[j].home_team: HOB team[k].name:RFC
i=1 j=0 round[i].match[j].home_team: HOB team[k].name:RFC
Segmentation fault: 11


typedef struct {
  char name[TEAM_SIZE];
  int points, matches_played, 
    matches_won, matches_draw, matches_lost, 
    matches_won_home, matches_won_away,
    goals_for, goals_against, goal_difference;
    double spectators_home_last_year;
} TEAM;
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  Also, is this supposed to be `C++`?  Or is it really `C`?  I see very little. if any usage of `C++` entities such as `std::string` or containers (which would reduce your reliance on pointers and char arrays).

Comment: Print the length of round[I] at the beginning of the inner iteration, and length round[I[.match[j] in the inner one.

Comment: The segfault is obviously caused by either 1) giving `strcmp` invalid addresses, or 2) giving it addresses of char arrays that were not null terminated and `strcmp` went into hyperspace looking for the terminating null.  Take your pick as to which one it is.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for your insight. Must be because the char arrays are not null-terminated then. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: @kabanus Added it to the description :-).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie And sorry for the first c++ tag. You are completely right - it is ansi c 89. New here on stackoverflow :-).

Comment: @jdoe Make sure that the `name` field is filled with '\0' before setting it.  It would also help if you posted exactly what these variables you're using in `strcmp` are declared as.

Comment: @jdoe `team[i].name = round[0].match[k].home_team;`  -- If your goal was to copy the character array from `home_team` to `name`, this does not do the job.  All you're doing is copying pointers, not characters.  That's why you should post what these variables are declared as.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Checking up on it all. Give me a sec :-). When I try to use strcpy I get some serious issues now.

Comment: @jdoe Of course it "works" if you copy a pointer that happens to be valid to another pointer variable.  However doing that means you have two pointers pointing to the same location, and if you invalidate that location (goes out of scope, `free()` is called, whatever), that other pointer now points to junk.  But if you really have two independent character buffers, you don't set one to the other by copying the pointer.  You set it by copying the characters from one buffer to the other.  If that was what you're supposed to be doing, and you get a crash, fix *that* problem correctly.

Comment: Also, you didn't post the actual declaration of those variables.  If they are char arrays, and they are not big enough to hold the characters, *including the terminating NULL character*, then you have a memory overwrite error if you attempted `strcpy`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you so much for you help. You are completely right.

Comment: For debugging memory errors try Valgrind: http://valgrind.org/

Comment: Also, you should be setting `k = 0` at the beginning of the inner for loop.